# Zooming < img> by scrolling without changing the marker position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

background:
I search a lot before I asking that here... 
I had an regular `<img>`  inside `<div>` element. 
On the image I put markers.
I want to zoom in to the image without changing the div element size 
and without to stretching the image under the div something that will move the marker from his current position.

There is any way to scrolling inside the image by Pixeling?

Comment: show your code please and what you tried so far

Comment: It's a little complicated, imagine an image inside div element that had on it marker in specific (pageX, pageY) position, I would like to zoom in and out by mouse wheel without changing the marker position
very similar to this [demo](http://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom/)  just with a marker that stays relative on his position on the map (for example if I put the marker on window corner after zoon in it will stay on the same position on the picture just the picture will zoomed in)

Comment: see here:https://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-zoom-into-an-image-on-scroll/

Comment: and here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322572/angular-image-zoom-always-in-center

Comment: Thanks for your time but those two solutions are not capable of my needs.
I need something that will stay on his div frame without moving

Comment: so show what you tried...

Comment: There is a simple example for this issue, 
[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lcnwv2o/2/)
I have `<img>` inside `<div>` that can put a marker on this image.
Assume that I can drag this marker,  
I would like to apply the ability to zoom to the picture to check if the marker placed in the correct position on the picture.
This should happen by this terms:
1. when the picture zoom in the div element has to remain in the same size and just the image zoom in.
2. the marker needs to remain in the position that he is placed **on the picture**

Comment: for example, if the marker placed on the left top corner of any who window when I zoom in to the picture I want that the marker will stay on the left top corner of a window! and not change his position by the zooming